# How do I add a string from an Excel workbook into an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to get an import data from an Excel workbook into an list, but I'm getting an error. Please see my code and error below.

`import pandas as pd`

`string_a = []`

`df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/mr938ur/Documents/EROA Pull/Example.xlsm',
                   header = None, 
                   sheet_name = 'Sheet 1'
                   )`

`string_a <- df.iloc[0,0]`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "<ipython-input-53-0859a4b01acd>", line 13, in <module>`
`string_a <- df.iloc[0,0]`

`TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`

When I check the type and value of df.iloc[0,0], i get the following:

`df.iloc[0,0]`
`Out[55]: 'Example string'`

`type(df.iloc[0,0])`
`Out[56]: str`

I would expect to be able to store a string into a list, but it isn't working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is pandas available in R? otherwise your <- should be = instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
string_a = df.iloc[0,0]
```